# Centering text in label and making entire label clickable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

im trying to style a file input button but I'm running into this annoying issue using labels.
[image]

This is the button in question, my first question is how could I make the text centered in the label.
My second question is that when my cursor is in the upper half of the button it is clickable but the other half is not how could I make the entire button clickable?

[image]

[image]

its also important that the button isn't weirdly positioned and retains the same position as in this picture
[image]

Im using bootstrap along with a custom CSS file

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

input[type="file"] {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 6px 180px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
<div class="fixed-bottom bg-secondary container" style="border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;">
    <input id="texture-upload" class="pt-2" type="file">
    <input id="texture-upload" class="pt-2" type="file">
    <label for="texture-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <p class="text-white text-center pt-2">Select texture folder</p>
    </label>
    <a class="fixed-bottom text-secondary text-center pb-2">Made with ❤️ by Maloni</a>
 </div>
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/mal0n1/pen/podjOmp

Comment: I've provided you a potential solution you may want to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bounding-box" of your element is equal to the elements size + padding + borders. It depends on how you set the `box-sizing` attribute - it will determine whether the padding should be taken into account. Margins don't count for the size.

For the layout: Use flexbox. It is super flex-ible (pun intended) for aligning stuff.

You can set `justify-content-center` to make the elements inside the flexbox-container horizontally centered and `align-items-center` to make the vertically centered.

I've simplified your code a little bit and added the centering:

```css
input[type="file"] {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.footer {
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
}

.upload {
  gap: 10px;
}

.custom-file-upload {
  background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body class="bg-dark">
  <footer class="fixed-bottom bg-secondary container p-2 footer">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center upload">
      <input id="texture-upload" class="pt-2 flex1" type="file">
      <input id="texture-upload" class="pt-2 flex2" type="file">
      <label for="texture-upload" class="p-2 text-white custom-file-upload">Select texture folder</label>
      <a class="text-white">Made with ❤️ by Maloni</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm this is quite odd, looking at your snippet it works great but applying it to my code it works great except for the fact that it isn't aligned in the center but instead all the way to the right. Also testing it out on my codepen doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Maloni You are probably missing a class somewhere. Can you update your snippet then so I can double-check?

Comment: Should be updated now.

Comment: @Maloni The difference is that `container` class also applies `display: flex` on your live-example.

Answer (score 0):

You can center your text by making it absolute, and positioning it with `top` and `left`

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

input[type="file"] {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom-file-upload {
  background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  width: 480px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-file-upload p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

And as we make the text absolute, we will have to give width and height to `.custom-file-upload`. I think it will solve the cursor problem as well. It's working fine in my device.

Is this the output you desire?

[image]

Comment: Although it gets centered, it doesnt center it in the middle of the custom-file-upload and rather centers it in the middle of the bar stretching the label.

Comment: @Maloni , I pasted the entire CSS I used. Is it the same as you?

Comment: Setting the position to absolute in the .custom-file-upload completely removes the bar, so I removed it. I made a imgur page to show my desired result and the result your CSS gave me.
https://imgur.com/a/dSXnWR9

Answer (score 0):

consider using flex instead of grid. easier to center,

so for your custom css .container class - `display: flex` then on the parent, use both `justify-content: center`, `alignItems:center`. move your `cursor: pointer` to the parent div i.e .container, only the label has it that's why it's the only clickable part. if you want more clarity. make a codepen and add it to your initial question and I can edit it myself

Comment: See the issue with the clickable part is, that if you click on the lower half of the button the input file pop up won't appear which is problematic, applying it to the whole container will give the illusion that it is clickable but it wont actually work. I have added a codepen to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding:5px;
}

input[type="file"] {
  display:none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="fixed-bottom container bg-secondary d-flex" style="border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;">
    <input id="texture-upload" class="pt-2" type="file">
    <label for="texture-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <p class="text-white text-center pt-2">Select texture folder</p>
    </label>
    <a class="text-secondary">Made with ❤️ by Maloni</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll work

```
.custom-file-upload p{
background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 5px 30px 12px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
```

}